# Make function type have conditional optional argument

Tags: typescript, redux

I have two generic types to use with my redux actions and action creators.  I am trying to conditionally make a generic function type have an optional argument based on a passed in argument.  Is there a more elegant way to write `GenericActionCreator` below?

```js
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

interface GenericAction<TType extends string, TPayload = undefined> extends AnyAction {
  type: TType;
  payload: TPayload;
}

// This function checks if the payload property on the passed in TAction can be undefined.
// If it can be undefined, then the payload argument becomes optional, otherwise it is
// required. 
type GenericActionCreator<
  TAction extends GenericAction<string, TAction['payload']>
> = Extract<TAction['payload'], undefined> extends never
  ? (payload: TAction['payload']) => TAction
  : (payload?: TAction['payload']) => TAction;


type RequiredPayloadAction = GenericAction<string, boolean>;
type RequiredPayloadActionCreator = GenericActionCreator<RequiredPayloadAction>;
// output: type RequiredPayloadActionCreator = (payload: boolean) => RequiredPayloadAction

type OptionalPayloadAction = GenericAction<string, boolean | undefined>;
type OptionalPayloadActionCreator = GenericActionCreator<OptionalPayloadAction>;
// output: type OptionalPayloadActionCreator = (payload?: boolean | undefined) => OptionalPayloadAction
```

You can see that if the payload can be undefined, it makes the payload argument optional, otherwise it requires it.  Is there a more efficient way to write it?

Comment: Do you consider `type GenericActionCreator<T extends GenericAction<string, P>, P = T["payload"]> = (...p: undefined extends P ? [P?] : [P]) => T;` any better?  I don't know if there's any relevant difference between them, though, without seeing more use cases in action.

Comment: Yes I think that looks a little nicer, but could you explain a little more what is going on there (e.g., wrapping `P` in `[]`)?  Feel free to write an answer

Comment: And you can define the value of `P` in a second argument to `GenericAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your existing `GenericActionCreator<T>` works for your use cases, it looks fine to me.

There are, of course, different ways to get the behavior you're talking about... but I don't know that any of them are more "elegant" (or at least it's somewhat  a matter of opinion).  Here's a version which gives the same output types as yours (note that function parameter names are not considered part of the type... so `(x: string)=>void` and `(y: string)=>void` are the same type) but expresses it differently:

```
type GenericActionCreator<T extends GenericAction<string, unknown>, P = T["payload"]> =
  (...p: undefined extends P ? [P?] : [P]) => T
```

I'll explain each change, and note that each change can be applied or not independently of the others, so you can abandon any change you don't like:

- I've replaced `TAction` with `T`.  This is only a cosmetic change.
- `T extends GenericAction<string, T["payload"]>` is recursive but does not need to be; instead, you could replace it with `T extends GenericAction<string, unknown>`, because any `T` assignable to `GenericAction<string, unknown>` will by necessity be assignable to `GenericAction<string, T["payload"]>`
- The lookup `T["payload"]` is being done multiple times in your version; there are different ways to avoid repeating this lookup.  One is to assign it to a new generic type variable `P` whose default is the value you want; that's what I've done with `type GAC<T, P = T["payload"]> = ⋯`.  Another way is to use conditional type inference: `type GAC<T> = T["payload"] extends infer P ? ⋯: never`.
- Since both branches of your conditional type look like `(⋯) => T`, it might be possible to push the conditional type into the parameter list of the function, to avoid duplicating the function signature.  There's a [relationship between parameter lists and tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) we can use to do this:  The function type `(x: X)=>void` can also be written `(...xs: [X])=>void`; the former is a function of one argument of type `X`, while the latter is a function whose list of arguments is a one-element tuple of type `X`.  And the function type `(x?: X)=>void` can also be written `(...xs: [X?])=>void`; the former is a function of one optional argument of type `X`, while the latter is a function whose list of arguments is a one-element [optional tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) of type `X`.  That question mark after the type in the tuple denotes it as optional... you can think of `[X?]` as similar to the union `[] | [X]`.

Okay, hope that helps give you some options and direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQHYE9kGMbAquAXzgDMoIQ4ByKAUwBMBXADyoG4BYAKG+FRlpQSAQyy04AcVqpBwLNlz4APABUV6MONrMBqegGc4+mFD4BzADRwVABWHoANhGH04AXjiM9tEnwYA+OG1dAxQMBTwCBG44OBgNWgAua3VNTi5YsHsnF2TbbOd6dMJubnjNSWlZeRxIgGE6YRhoVSCdaVCpGVMaxVQlY1NUS09UAGtUCAB3VH8rG3drAG0AIizHQpWAXUC3GLgACgA6E7Bkr3ofP1dgjsMFgH44JZsHrbhkl62ASndAlVKXHK4gASrQAI6MYB0eh2DYuCL4RZdaqI-qDcxWABGEAgDlowlm6WBcDBkOhDDhOXoaIaBOaUGRVR6tMaDKUZKhMKphTR-nSZQScAA8mA+sIHDyEbUkR4USyZeiTJi4Di8QSCAAfUaXXwyej8wUVUXiyUFaV9OlNaBM7pyVn0lomyISqU0xX8oA)